How to install python reflex on a Droplet Ubuntu
Te complete prosses to install reflex all throw set up the sites-available.conf for the proxy so I can use 3000 and 8000.
I try to run and is to slow and ending with error -39
Please if anyone is able to install reflex in a remote server like linode or Digital Ocean Droplets please explain the steps.
